# @Input gets the variable name from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I am trying to migrate my AngularJS app to Angular.

I have some components with bindings which needs to be converted to Angular

AngularJS Code:

```
<my-comp test="test.data" otherData="test.otherData"><my-comp>
```

my-comp.ts:

```
export default {
    template: html,
    bindings: {
        test: '<',
        otherData: '=',
    },
}
```

my-comp.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="val in $ctrl.test">
    {{ val }}
</div>
```

output: 
1
2
3

Now I have migrated my-comp.ts from AngularJS to Angular

my-comp.ts:

```
export class MyCompComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() test: any;
    @Input() otherData: any;
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('test: ', this.test);  // prints "test.data"
        console.log('otherData: ', this.otherData); // prints "test.otherData"
    }
}
```

my-comp.html:

```
{{ test }}
```

Actual output:
"test.data"

Expected output:
1 2 3

I am using @Input for bindings with '=' and '<'

I downgrade the updated component so it can be used in AngularJS code in

```
<my-comp test="test.data" otherData="test.otherData"><my-comp>
```

without having to write it as

```
<my-comp [test]="test.data" [otherData]="test.otherData"><my-comp>
```

Update:

[Docs](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-angular-components-from-angularjs-code)

Using NgUpgrade we can use the Angular Component (downgrade) in AngularJS template and pass inputs with [] as regular Angular inputs

```
<my-comp [test]="test.data" [otherData]="test.otherData"><my-comp>
```

Comment: How do you include your component? Please show the template it's called from.

Comment: @Jeto Updated my question.

Comment: I think you may need brackets, looks like angular is interpreting it as a string.
I guess you do <myComp test="test.data"> where it should be <myComp [test]="test.data">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include your component like this, using square brackets. See [Property Binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-).

```
<my-comp [test]="test.data" [otherData]="test.otherData"></my-comp>
```

Comment: That part of code is still in AngularJS, so I cannot use the []

Comment: @dot-net-dev But u cant mix AngularJS and Angular so he have to update the html that the binding works in Angular.

Comment: Are you trying to mix AngularJS with Angular 2+? I doubt that's even possible. Your post suggests you're trying to migrate.

Comment: You could potentially use both bindings: `<my-comp [test]="test.data" test="test.data" ...></my-comp>`. Angular will just ignore the non-bracketed ones.

Comment: `bind-test="test.data"` will also work, if that helps.

Comment: I am migrating the application using Ng-Upgrade so, I can run both Angular and AngularJS. Since I have updated my-comp code to Angular, I downgrade it to AngularJS and use it till I migrate all of the code to Angular.

Comment: Ya you can do this but thats "quick and dirty".  You should migrate the whole part to angular and not make a hybridization between AngularJS and Angular